# Combine LVM logical volumes?

Tags: lvm

It's a server with 128GB SSD.

There are two LVs, / and /home.

I want to combine them into one since the space is limited. I checked the HOW-TO but didn't found the tutorial for this task.

How can I combine them?

Comment: I guess you don't have this problem anymore, but I had a similar problem a while back. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67993/32067 Maybe my answer will help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they are distinct file systems, the only way to merge them would be copy the contents over and afterwards remove the other one.

But I don't see that you'll gain very much free space. To me, this config seems ideal:

- a `/` of about 10 GiB, maybe more,
- a `/home` of the needed size, and
- resize the one or other as needed.

Comment: Thanks. Your idea worked for me and here is the tutorial that I followed. http://linux-bsd-sharing.blogspot.com/2012/06/howto-shrink-size-of-ext4-lvm-logical.html

Comment: If only one volume's contents need to be retained, one could use something like `resize2fs` after adding the space from the "unneeded" logical volume onto the end of the "needed" one...  [I'm stuck in a similar situation with a system that has a too-small root partition; I don't want to reinstall, and I've got a spare logical volume on the same disk... >< ]