# Merge partitions resize2fs error

Tags: centos, lvm, fdisk, resize2fs

I was following this guide

[How do I combine two logical volumes that reside on a single physical volume in LVM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67822/how-do-i-combine-two-logical-volumes-that-reside-on-a-single-physical-volume-in)

To merge `/data` into `/` So `/` would have 60G space in addition.

[image]

Everything was done correctly and the problem happens when I did `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_xxxxxxx-lv_root`, I got error below:
[image]

One piece of information is that this Centos 6.8 VM is in VMware and the /data is basically Disk 3 below:

[image]

Result of `fdisk -l`:

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

to do so ...

- save data from /data if needed
- umount your current LV data01
- remove PV from this vg (& remove this vg if no more used)
- add now that PV to vgsys from vgextend command
- use lvextand to extand the rootlv
- finally only use resize2fs on this one.
- modify your /etc/fstab to stop mounting /data
- mkdir /data & restore any data in it